# cursor to "wait" while "time-consumer" is running after it back to standard

Tags: javascript

the problem: after clicking a checkbox I change the cursor to "wait", but only after about 6 seconds the wait-cursor is to see. How to avoid this 6 sec pause ?

many thanks in advance
Wicki
code edited !

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Cursor-Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var k = 0;
    var t1 = 0;
    var t2 = 0;
    function cursor_wait() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
      t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
      k = k+1;
    }

    function cursor_clear() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
    function st() {
      setTimeout(calc,500); //wait a bit
    }

    //long time action
    function calc() {
      ta = (new Date()).getTime();
      var dummy = 0;
      k = k+1;
      for (var i=0; i<1000000;i++) {
        for (var z=0; z<2000;z++) {
          dummy = dummy + z + i;
        }
      }
      tb = (new Date()).getTime();
      tr = tb-ta;
      cursor_clear();
      t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
      alert("nach clear, k="+k+" all time:"+(t2-t1)+" computing time:"+tr);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Cursor ändern: standard->wait->länger dauernde Aktion->standard</h2>
    <div>wait-cursor erst nach ca. 6 sec</div>
    <form name="some_form" action="index.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="nameless" value="5"
     onMouseDown="cursor_wait()" onMouseUp="st()" /> Five
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: While your code is burning up your user's CPU, the browser won't do anything else.

Comment: When do you want the cursor to go from 'waiting' -> 'default'? Do you expect it to go to that state after the loops complete? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

First off, setting `c` to the cursor style won't do you any good. Even if `c` were defined, it would be a string. Changing `c`'s value would just make it point to a different string, not change the cursor's style. You may want to do this:

```
    var c = document.body.style;
    var t1 = 0;
    var t2 = 0;
    function cursor_wait() {
      c.cursor = 'wait';
      t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
      k = k+1;
    }

    function cursor_clear() {
      c.cursor = 'default';
    }
    //long time action
    function calc() {
      setTimeout(cursor_clear, 6000);
    }
```

I removed other code to make it easier to see what you can do if you wanted to clear the cursor after 6 seconds and not block the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I have edited the code, see above. The original variable "c=document.body.style.cursor" was null, because at this time the document.body object wasn't created. The mouseup-event now causes call of a little timeout and then the calculation.